# EHCP backup restore

Tags: backup, restore

i have restored a backup of echp made yesterday, and now i can´t access one of my sites www.macsha.com

It give me a blank page

any idea? Please it's really urgent!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try: 
ehcp daemon restart: in console: /etc/init.d/ehcp restart

ehcp gui->options->sync domains

then, check again. 
check the server logs too. 
what you see in logs ?

Comment: Hi, i already fixed the issue. It seems thar the EHCP restore changed my .htaccess and also the DNS config. I have changed that and now it works.